# Git Bash Open Command Windows

Tags: git, command, git-bash

I'm extremely new to the command line and just programming in general. I use windows, and I'm doing prep work for viking code school. In one of the lessons it asks us to use the 'open' command in Git Bash (we were to download Git Bash if we weren't on Linux or Mac) which will not work for me. When I type it, I get the error "bash: open: command not found", how can I fix this or work around it? Thank you

Comment: Use the `open` command for *what*?

Comment: anything, that's the point. see below for an example of opening .txt - but in Linux you could open anything that way, I think...

Comment: Use '"start 'filename'.txt" to open the file in windows Gitbash...It works

Answer (score 17):

No you can't use `open` on windows. I think the closest to `open` in windows will be `explorer`, which will open the file using default associated windows programs.

Comment: Will also urls properly with the standard browser!

Answer (score 12):

`open` isn't a shell command or a program name, it is a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

> On Unix, Unix-like and other POSIX-compliant operating systems, popular system calls are `open`, `read`, `write`, `close`, `wait`, `exec`, `fork`, `exit`, and `kill`.

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is based on [mingw64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64), and `open()` is not a system call on Windows. Simply calls an editor or a bash command to open the file.

```
cat file.txt
more file.txt
/path/to/editor.exe file.txt # like sublimeText.exe
```

[Julix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2848941/julix) adds an example illustrating a Windows path:

```
/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe file.txt(<- change that to your file)
```

Comment: So is there something in Git Bash I can use to open files?

Comment: @BrandenKennedy simply call any windows program you want from your bash session: `/c/WINDOWS/system32/nnotepad.exe myfile`

Comment: doesn't that deserve an upvote then? possibly accepted answer?

Comment: This answer isn't really on-target @Julix, and there are other answers that have more useful content. The OP is looking for a call equivalent to the XDG Desktop command `xdg-open`, not the system call. This command will run the client software configured in the OS to use for the targeted file extension. Hence `xdg-open file.pdf` is for the OP `start file.pdf`, and will start Acrobat reader, or whatever is appropriate, not just Notepad.

Comment: @NeilG thanks for expanding on that! That's a good point... when a user clicks on a file in windows something "like" a dynamic "open" must be going on to look up "for this type of file, what am I to do?" - wonder why we can't run that in windows commandline.

Comment: @Julix, better not start wondering "why can't I do that in Windows that you can do in Linux / bash" - that's a journey that will never end.

Comment: I don't mean it in a judgemental way, I think there likely would be an interesting historical answer to the question, maybe one of permission or company politics or feature pressure / timing / convention / prioritization. Would be neat to know which, but out of scope for this question for sure :D

Answer (score 11):

I found two kinds of command lines would work same as open in Mac.

```
start filename
explorer filename
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm also a complete beginner, but it seems that the command you want is `start` (at least when applied to a program or program-file-pair).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GIT BASH on Windows PC - then to open a text file, type **start notepad.txt**

where start will 'open' your file, make sure to add the file extension also.

You can use **start** for opening images too.

**start favicon.png**   *or*   **start readme.md**
for example.

(If you want to add text to that .txt file using BASH then type,
echo "type something with quotations" >> yourtextfile.txt)

Answer (score 2):

For Git Bash on Windows, type the .exe name of your editor, for example, Visual Studio Code exe is `Code.exe` followed by space and dot. So you write `Code .`, and it will open all files with your editor.

Answer (score 2):

`start` command works for me on Windows machine as a replacement for the `open` command.

Comment: Finally thought of ... hey Mike why not GOOGLE the issue and see if you can find it -- so did that with "bash: open: command not found". Exactly that and only that.  I'll be damned ... here's the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

look commands are little different in unix terminal and windows command prompt..
solution would be
1) Download git from https://git-scm.com/downloads this will convert your linux command to windows command
2) What is the command ..?? post it as well .. may be we can help

Comment: I did download Git, that's where the problem lies. as an example the command '$ open test.txt' should open 'test.txt' but it says "bash: open: command not found" in Git Bash

Comment: make sure you are not adding $ before the command and not caged b/w single or double quotes secondly you should be in the same directory for ex: my "test.txt" is in abc folder and your termnal is pointing on user directory or c drive  use cd path/OfYour/Folder/whereThe/fileIs/and that is /abc

Answer (score 0):

"open" cannot be used on windows. The closest to open in windows will be the "explorer" (to open the default explorer) or "explorer ." (to open the current directly).

Comment: yes, it was copied, the original one is not with full description, cannot understand by newbies.